# How braces affect code output

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

While I am implementing **Selection sort** method and executing it, some of elements are sorted while other are not. I checked over the internet about a correct implementation but I didn't find any difference except an extra opening and closing braces.

Here is my code:

```
public void selectionSort()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<=arrSize;i++)
        {
            int min = i ; 
            for(int j = i+1;j<=arrSize;j++)
            {
                if(theArray[j]<theArray[min])
                    min = j;
                swap(min,i);
            }   
        }
    }
```

And here is what I found on the internet:

```
public void SelectionSort()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<=arrSize;i++)
        {
            int min = i ; 
            for(int j=i+1;j<=arrSize;j++)
            {
                if(theArray[j]<theArray[min])
                {
                    min = j  ;
                    swap(min,i);
                }               
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to track where the error is but I failed so I decided to ask here about this logical error, I hope you to answer the question and explain how braces can affect the output of code in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(theArray[j]<theArray[min])
   min = j;
swap(min,i);
```

and this

```
if(theArray[j]<theArray[min])
{
    min = j  ;
    swap(min,i);
}
```

are two different codes.

1. in first code you swap elements EVERYTIME
2. in second code you swap elements only if the if statment is true.

Comment: doesn't the purpose here is to run swap method only if there is a new min value ??

Comment: It is, and your code runs swap EVERYTIME becuase of lack of brackets. You should read online about IF statement in Java, and how bracket and scopes work.

Answer (score 0):

The braces limit the if condition actions.  With no baces after the if condition,  only one expression will be run conditionally and the swap in the second line after the if will always be executed.

Search more info about the scope of if else expressions limited in Java by braces.

Comment: doesn't  the purpose here is to run swap method only if there is a new min value ??

Comment: Exactly,  if you don't use the braces properly,  it will swap every loop.

Answer (score 0):

> i am trying to learn java myself

You should really get a book about java basics and read though it.

> i didn't find any difference except an extra opening and closing braces.

But they make the difference:

Without the braces: if the condition in the if statement is not matched the `if`  skips the *next statement only*.

In Java the curly braces create so called *blocks*. In conjuncton with the `if` statement such a *block* as a hole is the *next statement*.

Answer (score 0):

See

```
for(int j = i+1;j<=arrSize;j++)
{
    if(theArray[j]<theArray[min])
        min = j;
    swap(min,i);
}
```

Above will execute swap method in every iteration of for loop. Because its in for loop block.

And,

```
for(int j=i+1;j<=arrSize;j++)
{
    if(theArray[j]<theArray[min])
    {
        min = j  ;
        swap(min,i);
    }

}
```

Above will execute swap method only when if condition satisfied.

Loops, if or any block will consider statements inside braces. If you don't use braces then it will consider only next single statement in block.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no brackets then the compiler adds internally a bracket only for the next line. So,

```
if(theArray[j]<theArray[min])
  min = j;
swap(min,i);
```

is similar to

```
if(theArray[j]<theArray[min])
{
  min = j;
}
swap(min,i);
```

That's why you are getting the wrong output.